# Class Decorator to Pre-Process kwargs for Other Class Methods

Tags: python, class, decorator

I have a suite of methods in my `CurrencyTools` class that I would like to be able to accept `kwarg` inputs for different currency abbreviations. For instance, I want every method to accept either a 'usd' or 'eur' `kwarg` argument. To do their calculations, however, the functions need the input to be in usd so the first line of every method would then be to convert non-usd currency inputs to usd using a `self.convert_to_usd()`. This conversion step seems duplicative. How can I create a decorator that calls the class method `self.convert_to_usd` to do this conversion "pre-processing" step automatically and pass the converted usd amounts to the methods? I am not sure how the decorator can reach the `self` to call the `self.convert_to_usd` method.

```
class CurrencyTools(object):
   def __init__(self, eurusd_exchange_rate):
      self.eurusd_exchange_rate = eurusd_exchange_rate

   def convert_to_dollars(): 
   #### ?? Decorator ?? ####

   @convert_to_dollars
   def do_calculation(self, **kwargs):
      # usd = self.convert_to_usd(**kwargs) if 'usd' not in kwargs.keys() else kwargs['usd']
      # decorator avoids repeating the line above at the start of every function
      # do calculation with usd

   def convert_to_usd(self, **kwargs):
      return kwargs['eur'] * self.eurusd_exchange_rate

# example use
CurrencyTools(eurusd_exchange_rate=1.1).do_calculation(eur=100)
```

Comment: A class decorator is a callable that accepts a given `class` object  as an argument and returns another `class` object (usually a modified version of the one it was passed). I think what you want is just a regular function (or method) decorator whose first argument is a function (or method).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A decorator can replace the decorated method with another function of its own design. That new wrapper function can have a `self` argument, and the Python machinery that makes methods get the instance passed to them automatically as the first argument will work just like normal. It's only when you pass `self` on to the original function that you need to pass it around explicitly.

I suspect you want something like this:

```
def autoconvert_decorator(method):
    def wrapper(self, *args, eur=None, usd=None, **kwargs): # self gets provided like normal
        if usd is None:
            usd = self.convert_to_usd(eur=eur)
        return method(self, *args, usd=usd, **kwargs) # we have to explicitly pass self here
    return wrapper
```

You can vary this a bit to keep on fishing out the `usd` and/or `eur` keyword arguments from `kwargs`, but I think the code is a lot clearer if you explicitly name them in the wrapper function's signature.

Comment: please use [`@functools.wraps(method)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.wraps) to preserve documentation and other function meta data when possible.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen: It's a little trickier in this case, since the decorator could be seen as changing the signature of the method in a small way (adding a default value to some keyword args). For the questioner's methods that have lots of required stuff in `**kwargs`, I suppose it isn't so bad, though I'd suggest that named arguments (even if keyword-only) are better.

Comment: yes sorry, I wasn't necessarily addressing your answer just adding for other people who don't know of `wraps` existence, if it was unquestionably applicable I would have just edited the answer.  preserving name and documentation is useful meta data even if annotations aren't applicable, possibly using `@functools.wraps(method, ['__module__', '__name__', '__qualname__', '__doc__'])` so annotations don't get preserved? I'm not sure, either way I believe any answer using wrappers should at least have some mention of `functools.wraps`, have a nice day :)